# Routing between SignUp and SignIn Components

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here's my Content wrapper which will either display the `SignUp` component or the `SignIn` component.

```
const Content = (props) => {
    return (
        <div className="wrapper">

                <SignIn/>
                <SignUp/>

        </div>
    )
};
export default Content;
```

Here's my SignUp component

```
class SignUp extends React.Component {
    state = {
        email: '',
        username: '',
        password: '',
        second_password: '',
        showModal: false,
        modalMessage: '',
        modalHeader: ''
    };
    handleSubmit = async (event) => {
        event.preventDefault();

        const emailValidated = await this.validateEmail(this.state.email);
        const usernameValidated = this.validateUsername(this.state.username);
        const passwordValidated = this.validatePassword(this.state.password, this.state.second_password);
        if (emailValidated === true){
            if(usernameValidated === true){
                if(passwordValidated === true){
                    const registrationComplete = await this.register(this.state.email, this.state.username, this.state.password);
                    if (registrationComplete === true) {
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            ...prevState,
                            showModal: true,
                            modalMessage: "Please check your mail to activate your account",
                            modalHeader: "Success!"
                        }));
                    }else{
                        this.setState(prevState => ({
                            ...prevState,
                            showModal: true,
                            modalMessage: "Something went wrong with the registration. Please try again later.",
                            modalHeader: "Failure!"
                        }));
                    }
                }else{
                    this.setState(prevState => ({
                        ...prevState,
                        showModal: true,
                        modalMessage: "Passwords do not match",
                        modalHeader: "Failure!"
                    }));
                }

            }else{
                this.setState(prevState => ({
                    ...prevState,
                    showModal: true,
                    modalMessage: "Username should be a minimum of 8 characters long",
                    modalHeader: "Failure!"
                }));
            }

        }else{
            this.setState(prevState => ({
                ...prevState,
                showModal: true,
                modalMessage: "An account with that email already exists.",
                modalHeader: "Failure!"
            }));
        }

    };
    validateUsername = (username) => {
        return username.trim().length >= 8;
    };

    validatePassword = (password, second) => {
        return password.trim() === second.trim();
    };

    validateEmail = async (email) => {
        const resp = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'bouncr/user/exists',
            data: {"email": email}
        });
        return resp.status === 200
    };

    register = async (email, username, password) => {
        const resp = await axios({
            method: 'post',
            url: 'bouncr/user/register',
            data: {'email': email, 'username': username, 'password': password}

        });
        return resp.status === 201
    };
    onClose = () => {
        this.setState(prevState => ({...prevState, showModal: false, modalMessage: '', modalHeader: ''}));
    };

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CustomModal
                    showModal={this.state.showModal}
                    onClose={this.onClose}
                    modalMessage={this.state.modalMessage}
                    modalHeader={this.state.modalHeader}
                />

                <div className="register">
                    <h1>Sign Up</h1>
                    <Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                        <Form.Group controlId="email">
                            <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="email"
                                          placeholder="Enter email"
                                          value={this.state.email}
                                          onChange={event => this.setState({email: event.target.value})}/>
                            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                                Please make sure you've access to this mail. You'll receive an activation code here.
                            </Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="username">
                            <Form.Label className="form-label">Username</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="text"
                                          placeholder="Username"
                                          value={this.state.username}
                                          onChange={event => this.setState({username: event.target.value})}/>
                            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                                Please make it atleast 8 characters long.
                            </Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="password">
                            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password"
                                          placeholder="Password"
                                          value={this.state.password}
                                          onChange={event => this.setState({password: event.target.value})}/>
                            <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                                Please make sure it's atleast 8 characters long and uses a mix of letters and numbers.
                            </Form.Text>
                        </Form.Group>

                        <Form.Group controlId="confirmPassword">
                            <Form.Label>Confirm Password</Form.Label>
                            <Form.Control type="password"
                                          placeholder="Password"
                                          value={this.state.second_password}
                                          onChange={event => this.setState({second_password: event.target.value})}/>
                        </Form.Group>


                        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                            Sign Up
                        </Button>
                        <hr/>
                        <p onClick={() => this.props.setIsNew(false)}>
                            If you don't have an account, Sign Up
                        </p>
                    </Form>
                </div>
            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default SignUp;
```

And here's the SignIn component.

```
const SignIn = () => {
    return (
        <div className="sign-up">
            <h1>Sign In</h1>
            <Form>
                <Form.Group controlId="email">
                    <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email"/>
                    <Form.Text className="text-muted">
                    </Form.Text>
                </Form.Group>

                <Form.Group controlId="password">
                    <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
                    <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password"/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
                    <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Remember me"/>
                </Form.Group>
                <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
                    Sign In
                </Button>
                <hr/>
                <p>If you don't have an account, Sign Up</p>
            </Form>

        </div>
    )
};
export default SignIn;
```

I want the text underneath the button to route to the relevant component. How do I do this with React router?

Comment: Sounds like you just want a link: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link

Comment: @jonrsharpe it's not a regular use case, the links are inside separate components, thus the question. I don't have a navbar with links directing to respective components.

Comment: Then what does this have to do with the router, if they're not on routes? You need to toggle whatever is being used to decide which component gets shown, but there's not enough information in the question to tell you how that would look.

Comment: @MatthewMoran edited and corrected

Comment: What do you anticipate whether it's a new user or existing one? What should be displayed by default?

Comment: @MatthewMoran either works but SignIn is perfect for default.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Manage state in parent component.  This is a basic example using hooks. This component will determine which child component is rendered based on it's state.

```
const Content = props => {
  const [isNew, setIsNew] = useState(true);

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      {isNew ? <SignUp setIsNew={setIsNew} /> : <SignIn setIsNew={setIsNew} />}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

Pass setIsNew to children and call with proper boolean values.  We pass this function and bind it to an `onClick` handler.

```
const SignIn = ({setIsNew}) => {
  return (
    <div className="sign-up">
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="formBasicCheckbox">
          <Form.Check type="checkbox" label="Remember me" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Sign In
        </Button>
        <hr />
        <p onClick={() => setIsNew(true)}>
          If you don't have an account, Sign Up
        </p>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SignIn;
```

Same thing as `SignIn`.

```
const SignUp = ({setIsNew}) => {
  return (
    <div className="sign-up">
      <h1>Sign In</h1>
      <Form>
        <Form.Group controlId="email">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Enter email" />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group controlId="username">
          <Form.Label>Email address</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="email" placeholder="Username" />
          <Form.Text className="text-muted"></Form.Text>
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="password">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Password" />
        </Form.Group>

        <Form.Group controlId="confirmPassword">
          <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
          <Form.Control type="password" placeholder="Confirm Password" />
        </Form.Group>
        <Button variant="primary" type="submit">
          Sign In
        </Button>
        <hr />

        <p onClick={() => setIsNew(false)}>
          If you don't have an account, Sign Up
        </p>
      </Form>
    </div>
  );
};
export default SignUp;
```

Comment: Dumb question, but if my `SignUp` is a class component, how do I pass the `setIsNew` into it?

Comment: You pass it the same exact way.  You access it in the `SignUp` component through `this.props.setIsNew`

Comment: This is what I did `<p onClick={() => this.props.setIsNew(false)}>
                            If you don't have an account, Sign Up
                        </p>`

Comment: But this throws up the error, `TypeError: setIsNew is not a function`

Comment: Can you log what `setIsNew` actually is?  You have this line proper: `const [isNew, setIsNew] = useState(true);` and you are passing it like `setIsNew={setIsNew}` ?

Comment: The onClick works on the SignIn page, but doesn't work on the SignUp page.

Comment: What is setIsNew in the SignUp component?

Comment: I've updated the question with my SignUp class component. Can you please take a look.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204991/discussion-between-melissa-stewart-and-matthew-moran).